# Search for elements in sections, without getting into the articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, search, smartsearch

I have created a somewhat complex site that shows a lot of mini K2 articles on each page, to make sure that everything is editable.

For example, I have a slider (each slide is an item), a list of logos of associated companies (each one is an article) and then some news (real articles for a change).

90% of the site's content is in form of these articles that don't actually have any "read more" button to see the full article, because they're being used to make more things editable.

My problem is that I want to include a search box and make the searches go to the article only when there is a read more link. But I also want people to find the associated companies and go to the main page where the logos are listed, if we follow my previous example.

Has anyone come across a similar issue? What is the best way to do this?

I've thought of Google Search, but it seems very painful to implement and not very customizable.

Answer (score 1):

Regular search plugins work in a general way. To find search results only "when there is a read more link", you have to create a new plugin adding this restriction.

You can just duplicate plgSearchK2, to create plgSearchMyK2 and add the restriction:

```
i.introtext like '%<hr id="system-readmore" />%'
```